# GreaseMonkey Document.Write or post HTMl at end?

Tags: greasemonkey

I am trying to use `document.write(html);` in my script but it looks illegal. I would like to write some html at the end of my document in a GM script. How do i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest would be:

```
document.body.innerHTML += 'some html';
```

More robust and complex is to use DOM methods:

```
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.innerHTML = 'some text'; // yes, yes I am cheating here again but
                               // what did you expect from a short example?

document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
```

See the [Gecko_DOM_Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference) for more info about the DOM API.